# AttributeError when using replace_urlpattern in Satchmo

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I'm trying to override the default category view in Satchmo.  I'm successfully overriding other views with no problems, but this one is throwing an error.  Here is the code I'm using in my root urls.py to override the default category view:

```
replacement = url(r'^(?P<parent_slugs>([-\w]+/)*)?(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'pasma.custom_satchmo_views.category_view', {}, 'satchmo_category'),
replace_urlpattern(urlpatterns, replacement)
```

This is causing the following error:

```
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the trailing comma in your first line. You are assigning `replacement` a one-tuple containing the result of `url()` call: same as `replacement = (url(...),)`.

Comment: Lol... One of those simp[le errors it takes someone else to see.  Thanks!